# Javascript does nothing

Tags: javascript

This following code do nothing .When i click button it should tell my how many guess computer has taken to find my given input. I am using Adobe Dreamweaver.What might be wrong ?

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

 <body>
    <p> How many finger ? </p>
    <p><input id="myNum" type="text"</p>
    <button id="guess"> Mafia </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('guess').onclick=function(){
        var myNumber=document.getElementById('myNum').value;
        var GotIt=False;
        var NumOfGuess=0;
        while(GotIt==False)
        {
        var guess=Math.random();
        guess=guess*6;
        guess=Math.floor(guess);
        if(guess==myNumber)
        {
            GotIt==True;
            alert("Got It");
            alert("You took"+ NumOfGuess +"guess");
        }
        else
        {
            NumOfGuess+=1;
        }


    }
    }


    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: If your code really is `<p><input id="myNum" type="text"</p>`, then you're missing a `>`. Also, `False` and `Flase` should be `false`.

Comment: I see several syntax errors... is there an error message being output to the console?

Comment: Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and read the errors.

Comment: Also, you reinitialize `NumOfGuess` every time that function executes, so it has no way of tracking how many guesses have already occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plea check your browser console, you could see that you've some typo's like `False/True` they should be in lowercase format `false/true`, e.g:

```
var GotIt=False;
while(GotIt==Flase){
}
```

That should be :

```
var GotIt=false;
while(GotIt==false){
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I am newbie in js and i had the habit of using java there. That fixes it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo. Replace `Flase` by `false`. You should also use `===` instead of `==` in your code, but that's secondary.